# C++:Browser set to default browser on windows 8/10

Tags: c++, google-chrome, browser

I'd like to set a program as the 'default browser', so that for example, it'll be opened when addresses like `http://google.com/` are opened by another program or Windows. 
At first I assumed this was the same as XP/7 (via HKCR), but I found that you need to use the `Default Programs` feature of win8[+]. The relevant key is stored I think, at `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice]"Hash"="/9CPwAgPN4s=" "Progid"="IE.HTTPS"`.

But I don't know how to generate the hash keys.

Any information about how other programs do this or just hints in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is done by the user, not by you. The hash key exists precisely so you can't. Hint is in the name as well : **UserChoice**